# OpenSuse - Command for Beep Sound (System Bell)

Tags: command, opensuse, beep

I have a source code that runs perfectly fine on Ubuntu, it does some copumtations, and at some points it beeps like this

```
system("beep -f 400 -l 500");
```

On Ubuntu I had to do

```
apt-get install beep
```

However, I migrated to OpenSuse (not my choice) and now I get this message "sh: beep: command not found", as the command and package are obviously different.

Does anybody know hot to trigger the system beep sound and define the duration and frequency? I have been able to find only one way to change the parameters

```
setterm -bfreq 500 -blength 500
```

, but no way to actually trigger the system bell (beep). The following things don't work

```
echo ^G
echo -e "\a"
```

PS - the system Bell is enabled at 
Configure Desktop -> Application and System Notifications -> System Bell
and you can actually play with this

Comment: You can also visit the [home page of beep](http://www.johnath.com/beep/) and compile the thing yourself.

Comment: thanks @fvu, this is indeed an option.
However, if you see my PS comment above, there is a way to "beep" through the OpenSuse GUI, so there is already something built in, which is a much easier option.
I will have your advice in mind though ;) thanks!

Comment: So, I did what @fvu proposed. However, one needs to have sudo rights, to do so, otherwise (e.g. at my work-place we don't have sudo rights) there is this output message
"Could not open /dev/tty0 or /dev/vc/0 for writing
open: No such file or directory".
In this case, you should `sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/beep` as proposed here -> https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117309

Comment: It is common (and accepted) here to add your solution as an answer, and if it's actually the best or only solution, to accept that answer.  This serves as a signal to future visitors that that solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I did what @fvu proposed.

However, one needs to have sudo rights, to do so, otherwise (e.g. at my work-place we don't have sudo rights) there is this output message

`Could not open /dev/tty0 or /dev/vc/0 for writing open: No such file or directory`

In this case, you should:

`sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/beep`

as proposed [here](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117309)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that on my OpenSuse 12.3 system, the bell is working in xterm or gnome-terminal, but not in konsole or xfce4-terminal.
If the same applies to your system, then maybe a work-around could be creating a shell script called "beep" which calls xterm and rings the bell:

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e "echo -e '\a'; sleep 1"
```